# Debian Package in Oracle Linux Container

Tags: java, docker, debian

Have a `debian` package which was currently running in Ubuntu machine as service. Trying to containerize it. Since we need `Oracle JDK` we are using `Oracle Linux` as the base image. Am unable to install the debian package inside the container.

Tried both of this

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "dpkg -i --force-all /path/deb_file.deb"

RUN /bin/bash -c "apt install ./path/deb_file.deb"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is oracle linux debian based? Afaik, it is RHEL based. So have you tried yum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle linux is not a Debian-based distribution. It is RHEL-based, so use yum to install packages you need.

Comment: should i need to convert `.deb` to `.rpm` ? Because normal yum install is not working as expected.

Comment: No. You need to find rpm packages for what you need to install. What do you mean by "yum install is not working as expected"?